# Differences between TensorFlow's Inception-V3 implementation and "Rethinking Inception" paper

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am currently trying to understand the implementations of the Inception-V3 network, that come with TensorFlow:
[1] `https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/slim/inception_model.py`

[2] `https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/nets/inception_v3.py`

Both Implementations are written using Slim on top of TensorFlow.

While the architectures behind both implementations seem to be almost identical (except for a minor difference in the last layer, where it is `flatten + fcl` vs. `conv(1x1) + flatten`), there are some differences compared to the original [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.00567), that I can't figure out...

1. It starts near the beginning, where the implementations use:
   (I will use the naming convention used in [2])

   `conv3:  conv([1, 1],  80, stride = 1, pad = 'valid')`
   `conv4:  conv([3, 3], 192, stride = 1, pad = 'valid')`
   `pool2:  pool([3, 3],      stride = 2               )`
   leading to an output of size `35 x 35 x 192`.

   But according to the paper it should be:

   `conv3:  conv([3, 3],  80, stride = 1, pad = 'valid')`
   `conv4:  conv([3, 3], 192, stride = 2, pad = 'valid')`
   `conv5:  conv([3, 3], 288, stride = 1, pad = 'same' )`
   leading to an output of size `35 x 35 x 288`.
2. For the Inception modules, the following architecture is given in the paper (with the recommendation to use type 10 modules "when appropriate"):

   `3x  Inception type-5`
   `5x  Inception type-6`
   `2x  Inception type-7`

   The implementation uses:

   `3x  Inception type-5`
   `1x  Inception type-10`
   `4x  Inception type-6`
   `1x  Inception type-10`
   `2x  Inception type-7`
   resulting in 11 instead of 10 Inception modules.

   Also, the two `Inception type-10` modules are different from each other. But I think this is mentioned in the paper somewhere.
3. If I am not mistaken, the architecture of the `Inception type-5` modules should be the same as a vanilla Inception module (as in the "Going Deeper" paper), except for the `[5 x 5]` convolution, which is factored into two stacked `[3 x 3]`convolutions.

   In both implementation, however, the `[3 x 3]` convolution is replaced by two stacked `[3 x 3]`convolutions, keeping the `[5 x 5]` convolution.

So, am I missing something obvious? Was I sloppy when reading the papers or the code? Is this artistic freedom? Or some kind of magic happening?

**Update**

While comparing the two Slim models with the Keras model by [Nic Eggert](https://gist.github.com/neggert/f8b86d001a367aa7dde1ab6b587246b5), I found a mention of a mysterious "model.txt". Some other Stack Overflow thread pointed to the arxiv page of the "Rethinking Inception" paper, where it can be found among the other resources  (download link: `https://arxiv.org/e-print/1512.00567v3`).

So I guess I will just resort to using the description in the "model.txt" file.

However, I would still appreciate a thorough explanation of the differences.

Comment: I also found differences in the paper and Keras own implementation. I guess the takeaway message is that you can just put together random blocks and still get a predictive model. I also had to think about the squeezeNet paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.07360), it shows that most of the connections are actually useless.